# R: Calculate 12-month cumulative returns

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I have a time series dataset, and I'd like to get rolling 12-month cumulative returns. Below is what my code and data look like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(-0.0195,    0.0079, 0.0034, 0.0394, -0.0065,    0.0034, 0.0136, 0.0683, -0.0063,    -0.0537,    -0.0216,    -0.0036,    0.0659, -0.0377,    -0.0568,    0.0039, -0.0191,    0.0028),
  B = c(-0.0211,    0.0021, 0.0014, 0.0358, 0.0009, 0.0153, 0.0071, 0.0658, 0.0033, -0.0542,    -0.0261,    0.0064, 0.0665, -0.0304,    -0.0507,    0.0089, NA, NA),
  C= c(-0.0176, 0.0144, 0.0057, 0.0442, -0.0152,    -0.0105,    0.0213, 0.0712, -0.0176,    -0.0531,    -0.0163,    -0.0154,    0.0652, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
row.names(df) <- c("2016-10-31",    "2016-09-30",   "2016-08-31",   "2016-07-31",   "2016-06-30",   "2016-05-31",   "2016-04-30",   "2016-03-31",   "2016-02-29",   "2016-01-31",   "2015-12-31",   "2015-11-30",   "2015-10-31",   "2015-09-30",   "2015-08-31",   "2015-07-31",   "2015-06-30",   "2015-05-31")

> df
                  A       B       C
2016-10-31  -0.0195 -0.0211 -0.0176
2016-09-30   0.0079  0.0021  0.0144
2016-08-31   0.0034  0.0014  0.0057
2016-07-31   0.0394  0.0358  0.0442
2016-06-30  -0.0065  0.0009 -0.0152
2016-05-31   0.0034  0.0153 -0.0105
2016-04-30   0.0136  0.0071  0.0213
2016-03-31   0.0683  0.0658  0.0712
2016-02-29  -0.0063  0.0033 -0.0176
2016-01-31  -0.0537 -0.0542 -0.0531
2015-12-31  -0.0216 -0.0261 -0.0163
2015-11-30  -0.0036  0.0064 -0.0154
2015-10-31   0.0659  0.0665  0.0652
2015-09-30  -0.0377 -0.0304      NA
2015-08-31  -0.0568 -0.0507      NA
2015-07-31   0.0039  0.0089      NA 
2015-06-30  -0.0191      NA      NA
2015-05-31   0.0028      NA      NA
```

I want to get 12-month cumulative returns for each month using the formula `prod(1+R)-1`(product of 12 individual period returns minus 1). The results should be:

```
             A(1-Y)  B(1-Y)  C(1-Y)
2016-10-31   0.0198  0.0322  0.0052
2016-09-30   0.1086  0.1246  0.0898
2016-08-31   0.0585  0.0881 
2016-07-31  -0.0050  0.0316 
2016-06-30  -0.0390  0.0048 
2016-05-31  -0.0512     
2016-04-30  -0.0517
```

`B(1-Y)` only has 5 cumulative returns because `B` has no data prior to `2015-07-31`. Thus, it does not satisfy the condition of 12 months (there are only 11 months between `2015-07-31` and `2016-05-31`).

I have tried `Return.cumulative(df)`, but this function gives cumulative returns since inception, which is not what I am looking for. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Try `rollapply` from `zoo`, e.g. `rollapply(df,12,function(x) prod(x+1)-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As A.Webb mentions, `rollapply` gives the desired result. You can also use a for loop.

```
a <- b <- c <- 0
for(i in (nrow(df)-11):1){
    a[i] <- prod(1 + df$A[i:(i+11)]) - 1
    b[i] <- prod(1 + df$B[i:(i+11)]) - 1
    c[i] <- prod(1 + df$C[i:(i+11)]) - 1
}

cum.returns <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Comment: This is great for monthly work. A warning for those using daily data -  the code above assumes that the data is regular. For daily data, especially when you just have working days M to F then Mon to Fri again you might not get the rolling answer in number of days you want. e.g. i:i+29 for 30 days might not be a month of time.